# Can I automatically install Flash Player on an Android device?

Tags: android, flash, download, installation

As you know Flash Player is not distributed on the market anymore, but I've got some apk of Flash hosted on the Internet (example here: http://d-h.st/w2B)

I made an application where Flash is required and so I was wondering if can make something that if a customer click on a button, it will automatically download and install flash on his device?

I found this code to download my apk, but it doesn't work on my Android device, why?

```
String url = "http://charlie.d-h.st/w2B/00010/Adobe%20Flash%20Player%2011.1%20%281%29.apk";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url.toString());
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Below link answers to similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428853/how-to-install-apk-file-programmatically

Comment: have you solved this out?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can download APK and **initialize** its installation process, but user will have to accept (or deny) this request. You cannot do the silent or unattended installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to download app and use this code to call installer:

```
File appFile = new File("application.apk");
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(appFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(installIntent);
```

Or you can do the silent on rooted device using [this tutorial](http://www.kanatorn.info/2012/01/21/android-install-apk-programmatically-without-user-prompt/).

or use below code to install application from market:

```
Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.mypackage.name"));
startActivity(market);
```

Comment: To download the apk i use this code, but it doesn't like to works whyyy D:

String url = "http://charlie.dh.st/w2B/00010/Adobe%20Flash%20Player%2011.1%20%281%29.apk";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url.toString());
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: look at my answer again. i added installing application from market,

Comment: check it out:
http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/